# MTP mount fails of samsung galaxy S4 on 13.10 on lenovo t440

Tags: 13.10, usb, android, samsung, mtp

When I connect my samsung galaxy S4 active to my lenovo t440 running 13.10,  the device is detected and I'm offered to look at in Files.   When I first upgraded, it would work about 50% of the time.  Now all the time the directory is shown in Files as empty.

I am offered the eject button, which does eject it, but no amount of remounts will allow me to see the files on the phone.  [hmm screenshot of this deleted as I don't have reputation points]

If I eject and then try mtp-detect I get:

```
> mtp-detect
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 2, dev 16
Attempting to connect device(s)
```

at this point it hangs forever.   The USB device is definitely connected:

```
> lsusb -v
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04e8 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x6860 GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]
  bcdDevice            4.00
  iManufacturer           1 SAMSUNG
  iProduct                2 SAMSUNG_Android
  iSerial                 3 59c264f2
  bNumConfigurations      2
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower               96mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass         6 Imaging
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Still Image Capture
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Picture Transfer Protocol (PIMA 15470)
      iInterface              5 MTP
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bInterval               6
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength          105
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     2
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower               96mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass         6 Imaging
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Still Image Capture
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Picture Transfer Protocol (PIMA 15470)
      iInterface              5 MTP
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x001c  1x 28 bytes
        bInterval               6
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         1
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 Communications
      bFunctionSubClass       2 Abstract (modem)
      bFunctionProtocol       1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iFunction               8 CDC Serial
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 Communications
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Abstract (modem)
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 AT-commands (v.25ter)
      iInterface              6 CDC Abstract Control Model (ACM)
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          2
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x02
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        1
        bSlaveInterface         2 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x84  EP 4 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               9
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 CDC Data
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              7 CDC ACM Data
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      2
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

when I connect the device, syslog says:

```
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.263614] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.282108] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.282117] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.282122] usb 2-2: Product: SAMSUNG_Android
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.282126] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: SAMSUNG
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 kernel: [772995.282130] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 59c264f2
Mar 29 13:19:32 Tile440 colord: Device added: sysfs-SAMSUNG-SAMSUNG_Android
```

I've plugged the phone into all USB ports (black tongues, so that is USB 2.0 right?)

Comment: Connect to 3.0 port, the one with blue tongue.

Answer (score 2):

MTP is a long tale of misery on Ubuntu.  I can't offer a solution to fix MTP (I've tried many), but I can suggest WiFi Explorer instead.  You run the app on the device, then point your browser to the URL the app gives you.  It works very well and is 100% reliable, unlike MTP.

Mine also intermittently connects with MTP.  There's evidently some sort of handshake with the device when you connect the USB cable that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.  When it does, you get the USB symbol in the notification bar and are able to switch between MTP and Camera mode.  It IS sensitive to the cable you use, but this doesn't solve the problem, some cables don't work at all, the white Samsung cable is the same as various other cables I have, sometimes it works sometimes (mostly) it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This may be different from your exact issue, but I have also been having problems mounting my S4 at home (Linux Mint 16 [based on Ubuntu 13.10]). Usually when I plug it in I get an error saying that it was unable to connect. At work (Windows 7, factory cable) it works every time. Once I had brought the white cable home and tried it in all ports to no avail.

Long story short, I just took a can of compressed air to the micro USB male and female, and it now mounts first try.

Answer (score 0):

May sound weird, but what solved it for me was using the original (white) USB cable that came with the phone. When I used a different cable, it would only charge.