# MTP Won't Work With Newer Ubuntu

Tags: usb, mp3, mtp

I have a Philips GoGear Vibe 4 GB, set to MTP mode, as it's always been.  This works fine with older versions of Ubuntu and works fine with Windows, but doesn't work with newer versions of Ubuntu.  The version history is like this:

12.04 - works

12.10 - works

13.04 - doesn't work

14.04 - doesn't work

Windows 7 - works

When you plug the MP3 player in Ubuntu the file manager opens the root of the device, which contains the folder "internal storage".  When you click on "internal storage" to open it, the file manager just hangs.  And if you try to unmount the MP3 player, that process hangs too, until you just unplug it.

In Windows when you click on internal storage, it opens and shows all the files it contains.  And in the earlier versions of Ubuntu it just worked.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe one year late, but... today I had luck with the same type of player.  My player has been mounted, but I couldn't access internal storage (which I can't access via nautilus even now). Try installing "sudo apt-get install mtp-tools" after that Rhytmbox, Amarok an Gnomad were able to connect to device without problem. I've tried installing some suggested libraries, but with no luck. With mtp-tools it works like charm...

Answer (score 1):

From the sources on the forum, it seems that MTP is a bit of a problem in newer builds.
(see [MTP mount fails of samsung galaxy S4 on 13.10 on lenovo t440](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440571/mtp-mount-fails-of-samsung-galaxy-s4-on-13-10-on-lenovo-t440))

The above listed link offers a workable alternative, if not a direct solution to your problem.

Hope it helps, good luck.